# Find the empty textfields through the loop

Tags: iphone, loops

I am using the below code to check the textfields whether they are empty or not through loop.
Below is my code, it is giving the following error.

```
-[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x997c930
```

2014-03-19 16:54:49.227 IS[2837:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x997c930'

```
 //code

 NSString *strText;
 NSMutableArray *arrMsgs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*Manifest Type is reuired."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*Suffix Code is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*Aircraft Registry is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*Flight Number is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*Embarkation ICAO/IATA required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*ETD date (Local) is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*ETD Time (Local) is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*ETA date (Local) is required."];
[arrMsgs addObject:@"*ETA Time (Local) is required."];

NSLog(@"array:%d", [arrMsgs count]);
for(int i=1; i<=9;i++)
{
    UITextField *tf= (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    int k=0;
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:k];
    if([tf.text length] == 0)
    {
        strText = [arrMsgs objectAtIndex:i-1];
        lbl.text = strText;
        NSLog(@"strText1:%@", strText);
        k++;
    }
}
```

I am not getting where i am wrong, please guide for above. It crashes at the if condition with above mentioned error.

Comment: I think you have set the same tag to your imageview which you have applied to your textfields.Just give unique tags to your all objects

Comment: @NiravPatel Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your `k` is `integer` variable whose `value` is `0`:

But when u fetch `[self.view viewWithTag:k]` it gives `UIImageView` not `UILabel`. `Text property` is of `UILabel` and not of `UIImageView`

Check if its `UILabel` or not using `iskindOfClass` like this :

```
id viewTag = [self.view viewWithTag:k];
if([viewTag iskindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
   NSLog(@"image view");
else if([viewTag iskindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
   NSLog(@"label"); 
else if([viewTag iskindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
   NSLog(@"txtField"); 
else
    NSLog(@"%@",viewTag);
```

**Solution** is `add unique tag` to `UILabel` like `999 or 9999 or 99999`.